# How to flip webcam using react js?

Tags: reactjs

This code doesn't give mirror webcam. how can I do that?

```
import React from "react";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";

class Component extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return <Webcam />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Assuming it is the top result when searching for "react-webcam", it appears that it does have a [mirrored](https://github.com/mozmorris/react-webcam#props) property

Answer (score 2):

There is a property named **mirrored**, which is used for that and it is a boolean value, if true then mirrored else not.

```
class Component extends React.Component {
render() {
    return <Webcam mirrored={true} />;
  }
}
```

For the front camera, following code works :

```
class Component extends React.Component {
render() {
    const videoConstraints = {
      facingMode: "user"
    };

    return <Webcam videoConstraints={videoConstraints} />;
  }
}
```

For back camera :

```
class Component extends React.Component {
render() {
    const videoConstraints = {
      facingMode: { exact: "environment" }
    };

    return <Webcam videoConstraints={videoConstraints} />;
  }
}
```

> More details on this page: [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam)